# Finding latest version Folder

Tags: php

Lets come straight to my problem, these are my folders:

```
Smarty-3.1.13
Smarty-3.1.15
Smarty-3.1.16
Smarty-3.1.19
```

this is how i get the foldernames

```
$smarty_versions = glob("php/Smarty-*");
```

results:

```
Array
(
    [0] => php/Smarty-3.1.13
    [1] => php/Smarty-3.1.15
    [2] => php/Smarty-3.1.16
    [3] => php/Smarty-3.1.19
)
```

now im looking for... em... may a regexp for **[glob](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.glob.php)** to only select the latest folder.

actually everything what i have inserted as the first parameter into `golb` what looks like regexp failed :) is there a way so get the last folder like this?

or have i do it like...

```
$smarty_versions = glob("php/Smarty-*");
$latest_smarty_version = $smarty_versions[count($smarty_versions)-1]; 
//works but i like it more tiny if possible :)
```

maybe you guys know a other one line solution :D

Comment: nice!!! :D if you make a post ill vote this up and accept it :D

Comment: ok, i guess there is not a really one row solution. thx to all helpers, have a nice weekend.

Comment: +1 have a nice weekend

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use a proper version string comparison, you should use [`version_compare`](http://php.net/version_compare):

```
$latest = array_reduce($smarty_versions, function ($latest, $folder) {
    if (!$latest) {
        return $folder;
    }
    $latestNum = preg_replace('!^php/Smarty-!', '', $latest);
    $folderNum = preg_replace('!^php/Smarty-!', '', $folder);

    return version_compare($latestNum, $folderNum, '>') ? $latest : $folder;
});
```

Assuming of course that Smarty versions follow a compatible convention to what that function expects.

Comment: Nice, never seen or used that function before +1

Comment: looks nice but... its not a one line code :D don't want to create a extra function.

Comment: @Dwza "Create extra function"...?! This is as close as you'll get to "one line of code". Some problems simply are not properly solvable with one line of code.

Comment: actually this `max(glob("php/Smarty-*"))` is what i was looking for but the guy who posted it to my comment deleted it and didn't open up a post ^^ (and it's a short one line code)

Comment: @Dwza that was me, its all going downhill ;p

Comment: @Dwza Such a simplistic comparison doesn't work correctly anyway! See http://3v4l.org/JC2KN. There's a reason a specialised `version_compare` function exists.

Comment: @deceze is it possible to pass more variables into the array reduce part ? so i can create a `getLatestVerion("Smarty")`

Comment: @Dwza I think you're looking for the `use` syntax of anonymous functions: http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php